# Issue after removing perl.i386 package

Tags: centos, perl, yum

I am using CentOS and I have tried to remove Perl from my machine to re-install it. For that, I have used 'Yum remove perl.i386' . But it results in the removal of other packages including Graphics. How can I fix this issue and how can I install all the packages that are removed.

Please help me in this.

Comment: is the command Yum install perl.i386 will work? Will it install all the packages that has been removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do what you want *without* disturbing other stuff is to

```
yum reinstall your packages here
```

Your reckless `yum remove` got rid of everyting Perl depends on, the log at `/var/log/yum.log` will tell you what that was, and you can reinstall.

Comment: Do I have to reinstall all the packages independently? or Yum reinstall perl.i386 will add all the removed packages?

Comment: Reinstalling `perl.i386` will reinstall that one only, that's why I told you to check what got uninstalled.

Comment: ok. So we need to reinstall each one(including XServer) using yum. right?

Comment: @sneya, Ouch if all that got erased. Yes, you'll have to install each of them again. Just Unix' a bit cruel way of teaching newbies to be careful, what is being asked will be done without any second guessing. Consider yourself thaught.

Comment: Thank you. I have re-installed all the packages that have erased and now it is working.